# How do I mock azure-storage table service functionality with jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, azure-storage

I have this function that calls azure table storage:

```
const azure = require('azure-storage');
...
function getProductMetadata(sku, locale) {
    const retryPolicy = new azure.ExponentialRetryPolicyFilter(0, 200, 200, 600);
    const tableSvc = azure.createTableServiceWithSas(HOST, `?${AUTH}`).withFilter(retryPolicy);
    const payloadFormat = azure.TableUtilities.PayloadFormat.MINIMAL_METADATA;
    const partition = `${sku}-description`;

    return new Promise<PDAPIProduct.Tabledata>((resolve) => {
        tableSvc.retrieveEntity('ProductMetadata', partition, locale, { payloadFormat }, (error, result, response) => {
            if (get(response, 'statusCode') === 404) {
                resolve(null);
            } else {
                resolve(response.body);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

And this jest test for that function:

```
const azure = require('azure-storage');
jest.mock('azure-storage');
const tableServiceMock = {
    retrieveEntity: jest.fn,
    withFilter: jest.fn,
}
azure.createTableServiceWithSas.mockImplementationOnce(() => tableServiceMock);

afterEach(jest.clearAllMocks);

describe('Product module', () => {
    describe('getProductMetadata', () => {
        test('getProductMetadata via azure storage SDK', async () => {
            const retValue = await pdApiProductService.getProductMetadata('213123123', 'en-CA');

            ///expect( something) 
        });
    });
});
```

But when I run, it errors out with this:

```
 TypeError: tableSvc.retrieveEntity is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong?

btw, I was basing my test on this article:
https://medium.com/@lakshaykaushik2506/azure-functions-unit-testing-mocking-azure-storage-npm-module-with-jest-34316fac6a69

Comment: When I console.log tableSvc in the function, under the test run I get this: 
tableSvc: function mockConstructor() {
   return fn.apply(this, arguments);
}
So it seems that it's not getting the full mock implementation :(  .. not sure how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the below code and it works. `document` is the table column where I store a JSON document as string.

```
const result = { document: { _: '{ "status": "OK" }' } };

const retrieveFn = (table, partitionKey, rowKey, callback) => {
  callback(null, result, { success: true });
}

const tableServiceMock = {
  retrieveEntity: retrieveFn
}
azure.createTableService.mockImplementationOnce(() => tableServiceMock);
```

Comment: My problem is that I'm using withFilter() on the end of my call to createTableServiceWithSas and that messes with the test. Jest doesn't know what it is even though I included it in the mock.